# What is the difference between "anObject != null" and "null != anObject" in java?

Tags: java

I used to write a test statement of Java code like "**anObject != null**", but I found some people do this reversely like "**null != anObject**". So, What is the difference between them and which one is a better way in Java?

Comment: There's no difference.

Comment: No different, no better. With == doing it in reverse avoids accidental assignment.

Comment: Random trivia: these are "Yoda conditions" :P

Answer (score 7):

Their reasoning is that if you accidentally forget the `!`, then you have an assignment instead of a comparison, which cannot happen the second way.

`anObject = null` assigns null to `anObject`, while `null = anObject` will produce a compiler error.

Answer (score 3):

this is somewhat related to yoda conditions :

```
"the force".equals(myString);
```

avoids null pointer if myString is null.

Answer (score 2):

It's a style of how people compare expressions.

Do not use `null != anObject` as `null` is a constant and is considered a [Yoda condition](http://wiert.me/2010/05/25/yoda-conditions-from-stackoverflow-new-programming-jargon-you-coined/).

Always put the variable left hand side and the constant on the right.

Comment: It's not bad, there's no reason to avoid it... in fact there are advantages to doing this.

Comment: @Doorknob - maybe not bad, but I wouldn't really say it's convention. I personally find it harder to read and evaluate but it is preference.

Comment: It comes down to personal preference. Ultimately nobody will get hurt if you code this way. And you may protect yourself from doing something accidental that has a severe consequence in your compiled code. On the other hand it doesn't read as naturally as the correct way.

Answer (score 1):

From a compiled code point of view there is no difference.

However from a paranoid-programmer point of view it can prevent you from making the dreaded assignment bug.

e.g. if you mistype:

```
null = myObject
```

you get a compiler error because you cannot assign to constant.

However if you mistype:

```
myObject = null
```

the compiler will not complain. And you may release code that assigns null to your Object instead of testing for null.